# Why do we use getDomElement when parsing XML on Android?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

Why do we use `getDomElement` when parsing XML on Android?

Below my code:

```java
public Document getDomElement(String xml)
{   
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is); 
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc; 
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code permit you to simplify processing xml strings. It is just a function which encapsulate the first steps:

- you give an XML string
- you get a Document which can be used with DOM methods directly
- or he throws an exception

Then you can get Nodes, etc. :

```
 NodeList nList = doc.getChildNodes();
```